# Crate feature popularity statistics

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

The [crates.io](https://crates.io/) site shows number-of-downloads statistics and that's great. Is there an option to also see download statistics per feature?

As an example, for the [sqlx](https://crates.io/crates/sqlx) crate, which currently supports 4 different RDBMSs (MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server and SQLite), such statistics would provide valuable insights into how much the crate is used for each of those RDBMSs.

Answer (score 3):

What you download is identical no matter the features, it just en-/dis-ables code when compiling, there is no way for `crates.io` to know what features you compile with from the info it gets when you download a crate.